# Python 2: why xrange isn't called irange?

Tags: python

This question is kind of philosophical. There is splendid `itertools` module in Python 2, providing, in particular, generator equivalents for Python built-in functions like `map`, `filter`, `zip`, or `slice`. And the equivalents are called `imap`, `ifilter`, `izip`, and `islice`, respectively. As I understand, the prefix **i** in their names means **i**​terator. But there's the same thing about `xrange`: it is an equivalent of `range` returning generator object instead of large list. So, why isn't it called `irange`? What does prefix **x** actually mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `xrange()` was added to the language before it had iterators and it is itself not an iterator.

- Iterators were added in [PEP 234](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/), a proposal created in 2001.
- [`xrange()` was added to Python in 1993](http://hg.python.org/cpython/annotate/89e1e5d9ccbf/Python/bltinmodule.c#l915).

Python 1.0 was released in 1994, so `xrange()` was added very early on. The `x` most likely doesn't have a specific meaning here.

But `xrange()` is not really an iterator, it is an *iterable*; you can iterate over it multiple times, unlike iterators. It is also a sequence, as it has a length and can be indexed.

As such the object has been renamed to `range()` (replacing the Python 2 `range()` function altogether), and its sequence behaviour has been further expanded.

Comment: Thanks, yet what does **x** stand for?

Comment: I don't actually know; you'd have to ask Guido. I don't think it stands for anything. It probably is a reference to a similar object in another language, or just a prefix to differentiate it from `range()`.